# Sketching the graph of $y =\ln(4-x)$

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, exponential-function

$y = \ln(4 - x) $

This graph has two operations applied to the $\ln x$ graph - a reflection and a translation.

If you reflect the graph in the $y$-axis first, and then shift the graph 4 units to the left you get an incorrect answer. The result is that the graph cuts the $x$-axis at $(-5, 0)$

BUT

If you shift the graph $4$ units to the left first, and then reflect the graph in the $y$-axis you get the correct answer. The result is that the graph now cuts the $x$-axis at $(3, 0)$ and the $y$-axis at $(0, ln4)$

Why is that? And is there an order as to which operation you must do first? Can someone please explain in simple terms as I do not understand why this is the case.

Comment: Reflection of the graph of $y=\ln x$ gives the equation $y=\ln (-x)$. Shifting to the left gives the equation $y=\ln(-(x+4))$. This isn't what you have. Your second version works: shifting gives $y=\ln(x+4)$ and then reflecting gives $y=\ln ((-x)+4)$.

Comment: So what you're trying to say is treat y = ln(x) as f(x) = ln(x) and which operation you do, do it directly to x and try to get your original curve in the question?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Just apply the rules successively to the "starting function".

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the last option is correct, what I want to show why they're different.
This image, I think describes very well what's happening.

[image: plot]

The blue lines signify the translation, the red lines signify the reflection over the y-axis. The lower blue points are the correct method, the upper green ones are the incorrect one.